# PHP 5.3 and '::'

Tags: php

I started into PHP with 5.3 and am using the '::' to access constants ex; class::const. However, when I try to use my code in an older PHP namely 5.1.6 and 5.2.12, I get an error that the '::' is unexpected.

How do I access constants in these older versions of PHP5?

Comment: Might want to post the code that generates an error so we can try to flush it out for you.

Answer (score 2):

`ClassName::constant` should work. According to [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php), the following syntax is new in PHP 5.3:

```
$classname = "MyClass";
echo $classname::constant . "\n"; // As of PHP 5.3.0

$class = new MyClass();
$class->showConstant();

echo $class::constant."\n"; // As of PHP 5.3.0
```

A more complete code example/reduction may help with debugging.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
ClassName::CONSTANT_NAME
```

This should work in all versions of PHP 5.

Comment: How does this differ from the example given? Upper case?

Answer (score 0):

With the :: operator you can call only the static methods or access to the static variables/constants of a class.
 
The proper way is className::method() or className::publicVariable. Inside the static methods you can't refer to this because it's not called on a object, but from a non-static method you can access to a static varibale.

Anyway, the only new feature of PHP 5.3 about the [:: operator](http://au.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) is the ability to use a $string that contains the className.

Post please the revelant part of the code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem accessing class constants via the class name so I resorted to getters:

```
public function getSomeConstant() {
    return self::SomeConstant;
}
```

and in the parts where I needed it:

```
className::getSomeConstant();
```

**Edit:** in PHP < 5.3 that is...